# How to convert .NET DateTimeOffset into Sql2008 DateTimeOffset

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, datetimeoffset

I'm not sure how to correctly format a .NET `DateTimeOffset` variable, as a string, for SqlServer 2008 to correct parse the value.

currently, if I provide the default `.ToString()` value from a normal DateTimeOffset value, it errors.

Here is a sample `.ToString()` value that errors (eg. Sql2008 doesn't like it): `'25/12/2008 2:12:21 PM +00:00'`

### Update

Just to clarify, I know the `.ToString()` is not in a compatible Sql2008 format. I'm hoping someone might be able to tell me what i need to provide to an `IFormattableProvider` argument (for the `.ToString()` method) which is legit for the new `DateTimeOffset` SqlDataType.

### Answer

I've answered it myself. I figured out the correct IFormattableProvider args

`myDateTimeOffest.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff zzz")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[DateToOffset.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351892.aspx) supports passing in a format string to control the output.  Try passing in a format string which is compatible with SQL 2008

Comment: Yes JaredPar - that's EXACTLY what i'm asking in this question -> i'm not sure what that would be. I'll update the OP.

Answer (score 0):

According to [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx) the types are compatible.

What error are you receiving?  Are you specifying the Type System Version to be 2008 in your connection string?

Comment: >>Type System Version to be 2008 in your connection string. Er.. nope. what is that? this is my conn string: Data Source=fukchop;Initial Catalog=Osm;Integrated Security=SSPI;